# open source OCR library that runs on windows XP

Tags: java

I'm looking for an open source OCR library that runs on windows XP. I need this to work for images and PDFs. Mostly I would like to interface this library from java . Any idea if there is anything available?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/)

Tesseract is probably the most accurate open source OCR engine available. Combined with the Leptonica Image Processing Library it can read a wide variety of image formats and convert them to text in over 60 languages. It was one of the top 3 engines in the 1995 UNLV Accuracy test. Between 1995 and 2006 it had little work done on it, but since then it has been improved extensively by Google. It is released under the Apache License 2.0.

> Tesseract works on Linux, **Windows (with VC++ Express or CygWin)**
>   and Mac OSX

And here is a [comparision table from wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_optical_character_recognition_software)

Answer (score 0):

http://roncemer.com/software-development/java-ocr/

"Java OCR is a suite of pure java libraries for image processing and character recognition."

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the Apache Tika project and combine it with [Tesseract OCR](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/). Apache Tika manages opening and extracting content from a broad assortment of file types. And it has a very pluggable design so you can connect OCR for input and even wire it's output to Lucene for searching. And it's pure Java.

Comment: But Tika extracts text information, right? What about images(other than metadata)?

Answer (score 0):

There is huge work done by Heat on Research about OCR, have a look at [this](http://www.heatonresearch.com/articles/42/page1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Tess4J](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/), a Java JNA wrapper for Tesseract OCR API.